# Displaying Related Data in Gridview Using Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, gridview, yii2

I have being struggling with related model data for a while and can't seem to pin point the problem, I have been reduced to using a very simple example.

I have two models Dog and Owner, which have the following relations.

Owner:

```
public function getDogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Dog::className(), ['owner_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Dog:

```
public function getOwner()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Owner::className(), ['id' => 'owner_id']);
}
```

As a simple test I want to get the dog to disaply from the grid view in the index page in Owner view
This is my index.php in the Owner view

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'name',
        [       
            'attribute' => 'type',
            'value' => 'dog.type',
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I must be missing something fundamental here?

Comment: What's the current problem / error?

Comment: Current error is `Getting unknown property: app\models\Owner::dog`

Comment: Check relations, there are some mistakes there. They reference to the same type of object. And If the owner has many dogs, you can't access relation as `dog`, since it's `dogs`.

Comment: I am looking at the relations, but I can't seem to find any problems. they were generated directly from Gii. What problems do you see? I did however change the `dog` to `dogs` and now the page loads, but not the value, it just says in the Type column `not set`

Comment: do you use `->with('dogs')` in your query?

Comment: No. This must be part of the query in `OwnerSearch`?

Comment: @user2818986 what if an owner has multiple dogs? Will you have a row for each dog type (and therefore dog)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot display multiple related items like this, but you could simply use a callback, e.g. :

```
[
    'label' => 'Dog types',
    'value' => function($model) {
        return join(', ', yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($model->dogs, 'id', 'type'));
    },
],
```

Comment: The yii2 version of [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Lovely solution.

Comment: Thanks that's just what I needed. Now so you say I would not be able to display multiple related items like this but what about doing it the other way, from the Dog view, can I display the Owner information using my method above? As Any particular dog can only have one owner at a time.